# Where are all new SO questions?

Tags: bug, status-completed

When browsing in the "Questions" or "Unanswered" tabs, there haven't been any new question in about an hour. If browsing straight to https://stackoverflow.com/ there are many new questions, but they don't show up in the other tabs.

Comment: Well, it seems neither post mentioned by @Daanvn nor this one appears on meta, so maybe it's a bigger problem? A server problem seems  not unlikely.